# Can Rhythmbox sync to a subfolder of my Android phone?

Tags: android, sync, rhythmbox

I'd like to try using Rhythmbox to sync my music. I created the ".is_music_player" file on the root of the microSD so it is detected by Rhythmbox and I can sync my music. But when I sync, it syncs to the root of the microSD! Is there any way to sync to the "Music" subfolder instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that Mass Storage Device is switched on for your Android device.  This should make your Android visible to Nautilus.

Then, using your favourite text editor, create a text file called `.is_audio_player`  inside the root directory of the Mass Storage Device

Enter the following into the newly created file:

```
audio_folders=Music/
output_formats=audio/flac,audio/x-vorbis,audio/x-vorbis+ogg,audio/mpeg,audio/mp3,audio/x-aac
```

[source](http://support.gillhouse.net/Home/tips-and-fixes/synctoasubfolderonmassstoragedevicesinbansheeorrhythmbox)